# Show that $\alpha=\sigma_0$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Let $V$ be an inner product space and let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of $V$ satisfying the condition that $\alpha^*\alpha=\sigma_0$. Show that $\alpha=\sigma_0$.

I know that $\sigma_0$ is the 0-functional where $V\mapsto 0_v$. In this instance, the question does not specify selfadjoint (which i believe the condition contradicts) or that it is normal. Thus im not really sure if there are propositions that could help me.

I am clearly missing something in the properties of $\alpha^*$ as I am also stuck on the following question: [Show $\alpha$ is selfadjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011189/show-alpha-is-selfadjoint)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $x \in V$ show that $\alpha^*\alpha=\sigma_0$ implies
$$< \alpha(x), \alpha(x) >=0$$

**Full solution**

Let $v \in V$. Then, since $\alpha^*\alpha=\sigma_0$ you get 
$$< \alpha(v), \alpha(v) >=<\alpha^* \alpha(v), v>=<0,v>=0 $$

Now, since $< , >$ is an inner product space
$$<u,u> =0 \Rightarrow u=0$$

This shows that $\alpha(v)=0= \sigma_0(v)$.

Thus
$$\alpha(v) =\sigma_0(v) \forall v\in V$$

Comment: I began working in this strain, I will try again. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, Im not getting it... Heres what I have: $\langle {\alpha^*\alpha (v), v}\rangle= \langle {\alpha (v), \alpha(v)}\rangle$ which is =0 iff $\alpha(v)=0_v$.    Or $\langle{\alpha^*\alpha (v), v}\rangle=\langle{0_v, v}\rangle$.

Comment: @Aksel'sRose If you write that properly, you get the solution. Check the edit to my post;)